# No overload matches this call from react

Tags: reactjs, typescript

The code below is an error message. I think it's a problem with <IHistorical[]> used in useQuery. However, there is no solution.

```js
  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: Props | Readonly<Props>): ReactApexChart', gave the following error.
    Type '{ name: string; data: any[] | undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'number'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(props: Props, context: any): ReactApexChart', gave the following error.
    Type '{ name: string; data: any[] | undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'number'.
    29 |           type="line"
    30 |           series={[
  > 31 |             {
       |             ^
  > 32 |               name: "Price",
       | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  > 33 |               data: data?.map((price: { close: any; }) => price.close),
       | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  > 34 |             },
       | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    35 |           ]}
    36 |           options={{
    37 |             theme: {
```

my code

```js
import { useQuery } from "react-query";
import { fetchCoinHistory } from "../api";
import ReactApexChart from "react-apexcharts";

interface IHistorical {
  time_open: string;
  time_close: string;
  open: number;
  high: number;
  low: number;
  close: number;
  volume: number;
  market_cap: number;
}
interface ChartProps {
  coinId: string;
}

function Chart({ coinId }: ChartProps) {
  const { isLoading, data } = useQuery<IHistorical[]>(["ohlcv", coinId], () =>
    fetchCoinHistory(coinId!)
  );
  return (
    <div>
      {isLoading ? (
        "Loading chart..."
      ) : (
        <ReactApexChart
          type="line"
          series={[
            {
              name: "Price",
              data: data?.map((price => price.close),
            },
          ]}
          options={{
            theme: {
              mode: "dark",
            },
            chart: {
              height: 300,
              width: 500,
              toolbar: {
                show: false,
              },
              background: "transparent",
            },
            grid: { show: false },
            stroke: {
              curve: "smooth",
              width: 4,
            },
            yaxis: {
              show: false,
            },
            xaxis: {
              axisBorder: { show: false },
              axisTicks: { show: false },
              labels: { show: false },
            },
          }}
        />
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Chart;
```

I looked up the code in several ways for more than two hours, but I couldn't solve it at all. I have no idea why the problem occurred. I look forward to hearing from the masters. plz help

Answer (score 0):

It seems your biggest issue here is just that you forgot a set of parentheses and typescript is throwing useless errors for noticing that.

If you change your data mapping to the following, it should work fine. Note that the data the charting library is expecting is `number[]` instead of `number[] | undefined`, so I put in `?? []` at the end to make it so that it's an empty array in the case data is undefined still.

```
          data: data?.map((price => price.close)) ?? [],
```

Here's a [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=35&ssc=61&pln=35&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgVwM4FMCKz1QJ5wC%20cAZlBCHAERToCGAxjALQCOO%20VA3AFCiSw4AJXpMAgmHQAPAMIALOoLIVqtRizqSpDBbFTc%204aPBHrS5SjVEwDfAHYxcJRujgBJABLBUMaMAZ0ADaIPHBwMKDoAPoQknYAXHA%20UMB2AOa8YREg0QyBEBiJyakZoXCx6AlwdsggAEa4mXBywGlyiTX1jWX5AO4dtQ1QTXkF6ANdw2UAbhCBtePVg91hIIoA1ugwUQFgE0O8hPaOUM4MrvKKMAAK5GCoIWEMEKluACZFMCnphzwkyHYmMAIHZSFsdDIXnYvD5oHgABTPV4fJJfEoASkSnm8vhSAUCAG0ALqPOC0GDIKCg4k8I7-QEREFwS6weFIJF2d5ERIsm53VDo0nPOw%20RBwbwAGQgdDeJQANHA3nQYHQiHAALwoDDYXB4AA82NheKCxIAfPCCVQIHJAgxplQFRz3kSFfDBerTWUwiRwXJIakYbiEU63gBCdFldFNcmU0Hwr1wPWy6aesJpxCS6Wy9JwAD8cHj6fTVClMpKcB0VwAdDWqAmwoLEoWi2E9aZxFpefWizA8JJ1VRAql0HWW%20mMCl0Kh1QgCd2Wwh52O7HQcokqLd-CO5UuW0qVYl93Rc1W1mB4fCwHjXB64Fet1XRhh0YLc-niTux0XCJ%20v3AiUcf7lGAjIijOi5AVkcjoGupKQXAIAQG8ixUEqUDrA6u5pj%20WFPLoMCJBB8HNOgrRyARcAAMwAAzUb%208G9MAbwwO0cAAKy0fRkG%20HMdSKIRuFFqgcgQP0pBBBgXFAThxFwHxDDrGk5AAiiVBfHQIpgIolQ2FJY4yZBSlMYRSQiWJziBBgRB6S2yQQJsAmyQwlLTChqCIRALGYbJjHMaxAAsNnfkF6Z4HQUjeI5xHCaJiQWZJgkGUBUjhZFcGQalqAAELQMhUAmTF5kSa4SUZRFqAACr%20OsqAFWZcXFdZglhIEdANJZdWxeJlklSF2F9YQgFjgA9KmRbokNrbDcmY1RrSPA8NIAjwMhzjIIE8C8lwQA) with your example, as you can see, typescript now has no errors.

---

The missing parentheses appears to only be in the code you posted here, rather than the error message you posted above. The main issue overall is just the `number[]|undefined` vs `number[]` type, in which nullish coalescing is very helpful for.

```
          data: data?.map((price => price.close),
```

Whereas this was what was in the error message, and would just need to be coerced in some way to not include undefined in the type.

```
 > 33 |               data: data?.map((price: { close: any; }) => price.close),
```